# Java - JSP: Multiple login-config and auth-method

Tags: java, security, jsp, web.xml

Hello I have some trouble with my WebApp!

I created an index page with links to 2 different Site s(JSPs). I would like to protect these 2 Sites. The first site should only be accesable via Certificate (auth-method> CLIENT-CERT

I created the "security-constraints" in web.xml but my Problem is i don't know how to configure using, this " login-config ". I didn't found any good solution online which solves this kind of problem.

Do I really need to create 3 WebApps(Netbeans Projekts) which sovle this problem with 3 different web.xml files ?

greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Servlet specification requires that each web application has a maximum of one login configuration. If you want more complex configurations you either need separate web applications or you might be able to use a security library like Spring Security or SecurityFilter which may (I haven't checked) offer support for multiple authentication schemes within a single web application.

Comment: Spring Security definitely supports multiple authentication schemes within a single web application.